# Styling list items in a form

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty styling a `<fieldset>` that is a numbered list item in a form.

I've created a form and have made each question an item in an ordered list, like so:

```html
<li>
  <label>foo</label>
  <input type='text'>
</li>

<li>
  <label>baz</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</li>
```

Now I'm trying to style each list element so that each list number and the question (`<label>` element) appear together on a line, and the interactive widget appears on the line underneath. This is easy enough for questions that are made up of inline elements, but I'm running into trouble with check boxes and radio buttons that I have grouped together with a `<fieldset>`.

I've removed the default styling on the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` elements to try and make these questions look like the other list items in the form. But now I'm getting this really odd behaviour where the list number is aligning with the bottom input option (as opposed to with the label).

Changing the `list-style-position` doesn't help, and fiddling around with the  `<input>` or `<label>` styles doesn't seem to affect it. I tried changing the `<ol>` to `display: flex` and doing a few things with that but that didn't do anything either.

What *has* worked has been getting rid of the fieldset elements all together, but then there's no semantic relationship between the buttons and the questions, which I know is important for screenreaders. I'm sure I could also get rid of the numbering all together, but I don't want to. I looked it up before I started writing this form and there was nothing to say that nesting elements in `<li>` was an issue.

I found [this blog](https://thatemil.com/blog/2015/01/03/reset-your-fieldset/) as a guide to styling `<fieldset>` but it didn't help me fix my issue.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my issue (Q1 and Q3 are demonstrating the effect I'm going for; Question 2 has the weird styling issue).

https://jsfiddle.net/ocfk23un/45/

Basically, I'd like a solution to this issue or I'd like to know why this is happening before I abandon using the fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep using the HTML that you have as it is semantically correct. 
You just need to need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `fieldset` styles:

```
fieldset {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```